# Distance of satellite from tracking station given angles of elevation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In my 10th grade precalculus class, we are learning trigonometry. One of the problems we had to solve was the following:

> A satellite passes over two tracking stations, A and B, 100 km apart. When the satellite is between the two stations the angles of elevation at the stations are measured as 89°  and 87° respectively. What is the distance a, between the satellite and station B.

'a' is the side opposite of the angle A. I've made the following image to help visualize the problem:
[image]
Note: this image was not included with the original problem.

Using the law of sines, I arrived at an answer of 1433 km. This was marked as the correct answer. (My class is virtual so I do not have any interaction with the teacher other than the online assignments unless I email her). I'm quite certain this is the way the problem was intended to be solved.

Then I remembered that the Earth is not flat and at that scale, the Earth's curvature should have some kind of noticeable effect on the answer. Here's a summary of what I tried: using a value of 6371 km as the radius of the Earth. I assumed the angles of elevation of the stations were relative to the tangent of their location on the surface of the earth as I have hopefully demonstrated in this image:
[image]
(The angles are exaggerated to show what I mean). I placed the origin at the center of the earth and gave station A a location of (6371, 0). I found the location of station B using a bit more trigonometry. Then, I calculated what the slope of the line of sight passing from each station to the satellite should be. I then found the equation of each line of sight using the point-slope formula for each station. After that, I found the location of the satellite by finding the intersection of the two lines. Then I used the distance formula to find the distance between the location of the satellite and station B.
I arrived at an answer of around 1842 km.

However, I'm not sure if this is actually the right answer and don't know of any way to confirm it other than posting here. Is my answer actually correct? Although the curvature of the Earth should not be ignored, an extra 400 km does not quite seem right. Then again, the lines were almost parallel to begin with so any change could affect the answer more than I might expect. How would you go about calculating the actual answer to this problem? Is there a simpler way of going about this than what I outlined here?

Comment: I would have embedded the images in the question, but I need at least 10 reputation to do so.

Comment: +1 for thinking the problem through this way. I'm sure it's more than was called for. I haven't checked your work, or solved the problem independently (I may later, or someone else may). But the very small angles mean that the distance to $B$ will be very sensitive to initial values (you seem to know that).

Comment: The circumference of the earth is around $25,000mi * \frac85=40,000km$. $100/40000=.0025$. From this you can infer there is little difference between the length of the arc between the stations and the chord between the stations. The arc subtends an angle of $.0025*2*\pi\approx .0157$rad. The chord length is $2\sin(.0157/2)*\frac{40000km}{2\pi}\approx 99.999km$ - about a 1 meter difference. There should be very little difference in your results using the two methods. BTW you now have 11 rep so you can embed image.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post to directly image the image now. I'm going to try to work it out again when I get the time and see if I get the same answer.